# ASP.net Identity ChangePassword is inefficient

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-identity

I am using ASP.net Identity 2.0 with a user id of an integer.  Performing a password update is an incredibly expensive database operation with 2 (unneeded) queries both averaging 128,407 db time units, or about a 7 in the query plan, based on the amount of data I have.

Code I am calling (either async or sync are the same)

```
var result = await UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(userId, oldPassword, newPassword);
// or
var result = UserManager.ChangePassword(userId, oldPassword, newPassword);
```

In the database this causes two large sql calls which contain in their guts

```
AspNetUserRoles ... WHERE ((UPPER([Extent1].[Email])) = (UPPER(@p__linq__0))) ...

query 2:
AspNetUserRoles ... WHERE ((UPPER([Extent1].[UserName])) = (UPPER(@p__linq__0))) ...
```

From my perspective

- There is no reason to call this sql at all - a lookup by the int ID is fast, and the sql it is calling is looking up role data.
- using "Upper" is probably what makes it slow, and if there is no other better solution I can add a computed index ([System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider having performance issues/deadlocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977369/system-web-providers-defaultmembershipprovider-having-performance-issues-deadloc/19012766#19012766))

At a high level my question is - is there a work around for this, or can someone from the Identity team fix the code (if it is indeed broken).

**Update**
The same behavior can be observed for the following calls (and probably many others)

- UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync
- UserManager.CreateAsync

Comment: "or can someone from the Identity team fix the code (if it is indeed broken)."  That would be more of a request for Microsoft Connect.

Comment: Probably this should be closed as off-topic in the normal scheme of things, as this seems more like a Microsoft bug report. However, I suggest we leave this open in this case, so that an eventual Connect ticket can be pointed here, and the eventual resolution posted as the answer.

Comment: Logged at: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/849481/asp-net-identity-changepassword-is-inefficient-on-the-database

Comment: This issue was fixed with the ASP.NET Identity 2.2.0 release. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/02/20/open-sourcing-and-releasing-asp-net-identity-2-2-0.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can certainly do it yourself instead of calling that method.

Imagine you have, in scope, a UserManager<ApplicationUser> called userManager and a DbContext called context.

```
var user = await context.Users.Single(u => u.Id == knownId);
// You can skip this if you don't care about checking the old password...
if (userManager.PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(user.HashedPassword, "myOldPassword") == PasswordVerificationResult.Failed) { return; };
user.HashedPassword = userManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword("myNewPassword");
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

If that's still not optimized enough for you, DbContext exposes a Sql method, so you could just use the password hasher to get a hash, then issue a single Update() query.

I wouldn't do either of these things unless this is really a bottleneck or you have some other good reason, though.  I'm doing something similar in my application because, at least in ASP.NET Identity v1, there's no method to just change the password without checking the old one.

Comment: Verified this answer is much more efficient than the native calls.  Notes with Identity 2.0 it is user.PasswordHash and be careful to validate the passwords are valid (length, etc) prior to calling this code).

Comment: Ah, sorry, I am still using version 1.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer provided by @emodendroket correctly and efficiently answered my original question.  Due to the implications of needing to modify numerous parts of the API in the short term I am going with a simpler (but not as good solution)

**Add a computed and persisted index on email and usernames**

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.aspnetusers ADD UpperFieldEmail AS UPPER(email) PERSISTED 
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_aspnetusers_UpperFieldEmail  ON dbo.aspnetusers(UpperFieldEmail)

ALTER TABLE dbo.aspnetusers ADD UpperFieldUsername AS UPPER(username) PERSISTED 
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_aspnetusers_UpperFieldUsername ON dbo.aspnetusers(UpperFieldUsername)
```