# Find if one of current users(3.000) is in 5.000.000 rows big database

Tags: php, laravel

I have laravel project where I need to periodically check if one of 3.000 application users is in *Anti Money Laundering* database(5.000.000 rows big **Microsoft SQL** table).

In frontend I did it async with ajax, so when I click on "Check Users" button I will wait for response.

```
$users = User::all(); // 3.000 rows

foreach($users as $user){

      $aml = DB::table('anti_money_laundering') // 5.000.000 rows
                ->select('ID')
                ->whereRaw("LOWER([FULL_NAME]) = ?", [$user->full_name])
                ->first();

      if($aml){
            //Bingo, do stuff
            //Continue
      }

}
```

But I get `maximum execution time of 30 seconds` error and I think that **increasing request time** in `php.ini` configuration is not solution to my problem.

How should I do it? What is the best practice for big query/long request?

Comment: See: [Joins](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#joins) in Laravel and join the user and anti_money_laundering tables. I do think that just comparing whether the full names are exactly the same is a poor attempt at checking for money laundering, but hey, if that's what you want to do....

Comment: Also.... is the `FULL_NAME` column indexed? And since you're running `LOWER()` on that column, it might not be using the indexed data. [Here's a question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065001/sql-server-lower-function-on-indexed-column). One more thing, wouldn't it be better to store the user id in the `anti_money_laundering` instead of the name? Since the user id normally is an integer, it probably performs better. Plus, user id's are unique. A name usually isn't (unless `FULL_NAME` really is a unique username?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently running a query within a loop - and a loop with 3.000 iterations will therefor make 3.000 queries - that takes time!

Instead, you can just run one query where you join the two tables together and see if any results were returned.

```sql
SELECT aml.id
FROM anti_money_laundering AS aml
JOIN users AS u
    ON aml.FULL_NAME = u.full_name
```

In Eloquent, you can do it like this

```php
$query = DB::table('anti_money_laundering ')
              ->join('users', 'users.full_name', '=', 'anti_money_laundering.full_name')
              ->select('anti_money_laundering.id')
              ->get();
```

If there are any results, there is a match.

Answer (score -1):

Build up an array with usernames and check whether any anti_money_laundering record is in your set:

```
$users = User::all(); // 3.000 rows
$fullNames = [];

foreach($users as $user){

      $fullNames[]=$user->full_name;

}

$badUsers = DB::table('anti_money_laundering') // 5.000.000 rows
                ->select('ID')
                ->whereIn("LOWER([FULL_NAME]) = ?", $fullNames)
                ->get();

foreach($badUsers as $badUser){
    //Bingo, do stuff
    //Continue
}
```

Note, that I'm not fluent in Laravel or Eloquent, so if there are typos in my answer, then that's the cause. However, the idea is superior to your initial idea of sending 3000 requests (very slow) or the other answer which does an unnecessary join.